# C++ bool to int cast and GCC 4.8.1

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion

Do I understand correctly that `bool` to `int` cast should cast `true` to `1`?

GCC 4.8.1 gives strange result for this code:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    array<bool, 3> bb;
    for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) cout << static_cast<int>( bb[i] ) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get:

```
>> g++ -std=c++11 test_bool.cpp  -pedantic -O3
>> ./a.out 
136
251
160
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that `bool` to `int` cast should cast `true` to `1`?

Yes.

> GCC 4.8.1 gives strange result for this code:

That's because your program has undefined behavior, since your array is not initialized. Try, for instance, this:

```
array<bool, 3> bb = { true, false, true };
```

And you will see a consistent output. Here is a [**live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=073d5d8fc32600b92cc0570a399f71cc-0bcbabce5e03da787bd7f789f9dd7c18).

Comment: So uninitialized `bool` variable is not either `true` or `false`, it can be junk?

Comment: @user2052436, It doesn't even have to be junk in a way. Undefined behaviour can mean anything.

Comment: Oh hey, when did GCC start doing the brace elision for `std::array`?

Comment: @user2052436: `bool` is a scalar type, so its value is indeterminate after default-initialization (which is a no-initialization). Every attempt to read the value of an object with indeterminate value results in undefined behavior

Comment: Got it. I thought uninitialized `bool` variable will have a valid boolean value, just unknown which one (`true` or `false`); like uninitialized `int` will have some valid integer value. Did not realize that uninitialized `bool` may have invalid value.

Comment: @user2052436: Yep. Btw that's specified in paragraph 4.1 of the C++11 Standard in terms of the so-called "lvalue-to-rvalue conversion" (necessary when the "pure value" of an object is required). Applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to an object with indeterminate value is undefined behavior. But yeah, the point is just: "don't try to read the value of an uninitialized variable"

Comment: @user2052436: Typically an `int` is, say, 32 bits and has 2**32 distinct values, so *any* bit pattern is a valid value. `bool` is typically 8 bits, but only has 2 valid values, so there are 254 bit invalid bit patterns. In converting from `bool` to `int`, the compiler is entitled to *assume* a valid value, so invalid values can give invalid results. But even if there are no invalid bit patterns for `int`, accessing an uninitialized `int` value *still* has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Your `bb` array is not initialized, so your code has `undefined behavior`. You can see that [This Demo](http://ideone.com/Hndxm3) outputs different result.

Answer (score 1):

The the values of array hasn't been initialized, so the cells are initialized with garbage.